# Usage of $LANG in php

Tags: php, lang

I need to put this `{$LANG.home}` which equals to "Home", into this:

`$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php','Home');`

I tried:
`$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php',$LANG.home);` but no cigar.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $LANG? Are you using a framework, a library or what?

Comment: '$LANG.home' is suspicious as it does not follow any recognisable syntax within php. If you var_dump($lang) you can tell us exactly what $LANG is.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, it's -like @TheDrot said- a Smarty variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm going on a guess but if `{$LANG.home}` is a Smarty variable then `$LANG` is an array so:

```
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php', $LANG['home']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, it's a Smarty variable. I already tried that but still nothing.

Comment: @ManosKrokos Ok then first you need to find what and where is being assigned as smarty variable `$LANG`.

Comment: This is from a translation php file. This is how the variable is assigned: `$_LANG['home'] = "Home";`
In the HTML file, `{$LANG.home}` works OK. When the page is rendered the smarty tag is replaced by the "Home" string. But when used in PHP file (even as you suggested), nothing shows.

Comment: @ManosKrokos So try `$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php', $_LANG['home']);`